# C programming: How to printf an array of integers as a 2d array?

Tags: arrays, c

I have an array of integers:
`int* list = malloc((m*n) * sizeof(int));` Variables `m` and `n` are the required dimensions of a 2d array.

I filled my array with random numbers and printed it with a simple `for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) printf("%d\n", list[i]);` Which prints:

```
4
5
100
7
9
3
74
1
6
```

My question is how can I print the array as a 2d array instead of 1d?

Here's my attempt:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d", list[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
```

But this prints first n numbers like this:

```
444
555
100100100
```

Leaving the rest of the array lost somewhere.

Comment: `list[i]` -> `list[i*m+j]`.

Comment: @interjay yep that was the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row (`i = 0`) should print the element `0, 1, ... , m-1`.

The second row (`i = 1`) should print the element `m, m+1, ..., 2*m-1`.

The `i`th row should print the element `m*i, m*i+1, ... , m*i+m-1`.

Therefore, you should print `list[i*m+j]` instead of `list[i]`.

Also you may want to add some space between the elements in the same row.

Comment: I know about the spaces, I forgot to write that down. This fixed my problem. Thanks a lot :)